# "Drag" selected text using the keyboard?

Tags: windows, text-editing

If I select some text in a text input field/area/window, I can drag that text to another position somewhere within the text area using the mouse. Is it possible to do this dragging using the keyboard?
I can imagine some global key shortcut existing that would allow me to "drag" the text selection using the arrow keys; maybe even using keys like "End" and Page Up".

Comment: Select txt, Ctrl+X, move with arrow keys and Ctrl+V? (Cut and Paste) :)

Comment: Avoiding copy/cut-pasting is one of the main reasons I want to do this in the first place—don't want to lose what's on my clipboard. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using MouseKeys, it's not possible out of the box. You could probably create this functionality using something like AutoHotkey.

Comment: But mouse keys is built into Windows. That is "Out of the box" Did you just want to answer your own question?

Comment: That's why I said "apart from". I just wanted a better answer than the one available.

Comment: But the one you gave and accepted wasn't in any way better. If you want a better answer offer a bounty and leave the question unanswered.

Comment: I also look for a way to use the keyboard to move selected text for the same reason as the answerer.  The other answer presented here is terrible.  It shows you a solution to use the mouse to move selected text, but at the *enormous* cost of losing your numeric keypad.  Now if there were a way to turn mouse keys off and on with a keyboard shortcut then it might be an acceptable solution.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin: Actually, you can toggle it with Alt+Shift+NumLock, but I still think it's hardly a solution. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-xp/help/turn-on-mousekeys

Comment: I just tried it and it's uber awkward.  1) toggle mouse keys, 2) use the arrow keys to inch the mouse into position (really fun if you have two monitors and the text is on one screen and the mouse is on the other), 3) hit 0 to turn on button lock, 4) use arrow keys to inch mouse into destination position, 5) hit PERIOD to release button lock.  All I want to do now is take a nap.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to use **[MouseKeys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775624%28WS.10%29.aspx)**. It's one of the accessibility features of Windows [2000](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windows2000/mousekeys.aspx), [XP](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/mousekeys.aspx), [Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/mousekeys.aspx) and [7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Use-Mouse-Keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer).

Comment: [The detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/1802026/446090) of @Mehper's answer

Answer (score 1):

I just know moving lines in some editors. In [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> which moves the line up or down.

Comment: You can do something similar in Visual Studio: hold `alt` and use the arrow keys up and down to move the current line up or down. Doesn't work for selections, though; only complete lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mehper,

Here's the detailed answer (*for people like me who are looking for a k/b only solution*)
**PROBLEM:** I was looking for mouse keys for 'click-n-hold' operation as my mouse battery had died, and I had a constant need of clicking and dragging windows between laptop and the external monitor - and doing so with the touch-pad *was a pain*
**SOLUTION**:
*Searched for it literally the whole day*
[image] 
src: [MouseKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc775624(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

To get the effect of press and hold the left click, use the `Button Lock` button as shown in the pic

Try it once, twice and you'll get the hang of it, thnx

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>. This should move the highlighted text up and down within a larger body of text.

Comment: Hm, no that does not seem to work. I tried in Chrome (address bar, text field, Google Docs document) and in Notepad, but it doesn't work. (It does move lines in Google Docs.)

In what software did you find it working?

Comment: There are no global line moving shortcuts. They depend on the text editor

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code you can hold `Alt` + Up/Down Arrow Keys to move lines of code all at once without any highlighting.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be a universal solution. In what environment have you seen it work? … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.